# Restrict certain folders in content builder for specific users in exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to restrict certain folders in content builder for specific users or roles in exact target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict certain folders to specific roles / users on . Visibility of folders on content builder will be binary i.e (You can see them all or you can't).

A work around might be to add the folder to the Shared Content Folder and restrict the viewers or roles from access to it.

[image]

Shared Content - Content Builder

[image]

**References:** 
[Shared Content - Content Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_share_content.htm&type=5)

Comment: There is...it is on the other side of local ...in content builder. Will add screen shot

Comment: Are you an admin? You might not have the permissions to view this switched on

Comment: I have all permissions for shared folder but still the shared  folder is not there

Comment: Have you shared anything in your account yet? Try share something and the folder should appear